# What files will dpkg-buildpackage generate for a multi deb control file

Tags: debian, packaging

If I have a control file that generates multiple debs from a single source package, is there a way to discover what deb files will be created before running dpkg-buildpackage or pbuilder.

Below is a sample, abbreviated, control file.

```
Source: example
Build-Depends: debhelper (>= 7), fakeroot

Package: example
Architecture: all
Description: A silly example

Package: example-doc
Architecture: all
Description: Documentation for the example

Package: example-utils
Architecture: any
Description: Extra binary tools for example
```

Which would cause dpkg-buildpackage to create:

```
example_1.0.0_all.deb
example-docs_1.0.0_all.deb
example-utils_1.0.0_amd64.deb
```

Ideally, "sometool --arch amd64" would output the file list above.

Answer (score 1):

The source control file (`.dsc`) contains the `Binary` field, which gives you a comma-separated list of packages that *can* be built from this source (and usually will be). For some wierd architecture specifications, it might declare too many packages, and it doesn't give the architecture for every package, so it can't fully create your list.

Since `dpkg-buildpackage -S` creates the `.dsc` file and you need it for pbuilder anyway, it might be a good start. If not, you'll just have to parse the control file yourself. Of course, depending on your need, you might not need to parse the file at all - `make` and friends can easily be satisfied with building the `.changes` file.

Comment: Thanks for throwing in the .changes comment, it gets me 80% of the way.

Answer (score 0):

Most probably a bit late, but I found the steps needed for the solution and it makes sense to provide it.

If you have multiple packages in one control file, you need to extract them, e.g. with awk:

```
awk '/^Package:/{print $2}' debian/control
```

Now you can generate a single "pseudo" control file for each package and extract the info needed (name, version, architecture) with awk:

```
dpkg-gencontrol -O -ppackagename | awk '/^(Package|Version|Architecture):/{print $2}'
```

Now you have all parts to build the filename of the Debian packages which would be built.

I am sure some awk experts (unfortunately I am not) can create a awk script to concatenate the information to a filename, or just create a bash script to do it.